# How to provide access to the Internet using 2 different ISPs

Tags: networking, router, internet, lan

This is the problem: We have a contract with two different ISPs for different reasons, and each contract provides access to the Internet. The thing is that there are two different networks in our company and the goal is to let the hosts on LAN 1 to access and be seen from LAN 2 and vice versa, while letting LAN 1 to access the Internet only through ISP 1 and LAN 2 only through ISP 2, so that if users of LAN 1 use the bandwith completely, it won't affect the users of LAN 2. The proposed topology may look as follows:

[image: Topology]

[(click to see full image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HV5E.jpg)

In this case the modem provides NAT and a public address for the router to use on its corresponding port, and the map is over-simplified.

Is there a way to do this? So far I'm thinking about static routes (between the two LANs), but how to restrict access to each only through its ISP?